# Regenerate YAML Fixtures from DB in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, fixture

I am using Rails and my YAML fixtures are corrupted and unusable. I would like to regenerate the YAML fixtures based on the development database.

I am **not** trying to take all the DB data and turn it into a fixture. What I want is to recreate the *standard* fixtures that were created initially when the models were first created.

Is there an easy way to do this in Rails 4?

(I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915726/regenerate-fixture-test-files-in-rails) page that discusses how to do this [I think] by creating a rake task. However the Q is from 3 years ago and I wonder if a more direct method has been created yet.)

Comment: I think you should try using that answer you linked. I really doubt there's any better way to do what you're asking. It's not a normal use case.

Comment: Trying…and failing. :/

I am looking at `create_fixtures()`, but having a trouble figuring out how to use it due to the lack of documentation...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no standard or very elegant way.

I use this snippet when I need to:

```
File.open("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/users.yml", 'w') do |file|
  data = User.all.to_a.map(&:attributes)
  data.each{|x| x.delete('id')}
  file.write data.to_yaml
end
```

Comment: This is a very useful answer! (The linked-to answer wasn't working properly for me)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote rake task for this.

https://gist.github.com/kuboon/55d4d8e862362d30456e7aa7cd6c9cf5

```
# lib/tasks/db_fixtures_export.rake
namespace 'db:fixtures' do
  desc "generate fixtures from the current database"

  task :export => :environment do
    Rails.application.eager_load!
    models = defined?(AppicationRecord) ? ApplicationRecord.decendants : ActiveRecord::Base.descendants
    models.each do |model|
      puts "exporting: #{model}"

      # Hoge::Fuga -> test/fixtures/hoge/fuga.yml
      filepath = Rails.root.join('test/fixtures', "#{model.name.underscore}.yml")
      FileUtils.mkdir_p filepath.dirname

      filepath.open('w') do |file|
        hash = {}
        model.find_each do |r|
          key = r.try(:name) || "#{filepath.basename('.*')}_#{r.id}"
          hash[key] = r.attributes.except(:password_digest)
        end
        file.write hash.to_yaml
      end
    end
  end
end
```